# Event handled attached to form submit is not invoked

Tags: jquery

This is an extension to the problem already posted here: [display an alert message on successfull submission of a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143986/display-an-alert-message-on-successfull-submission-of-a-form)

Another problem has arisen now. Until now I was calling this function onclick event of a "submit" button. 
But now my requirements have changed a little. Now I have to call this function by clicking a link.
The html code for that link is as shown below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:customTargetReportToCSV('saveReport',0);">
    Save Report 
    <img height="16" width="16" style="vertical-align: bottom;" src="/img/icn_export.gif" alt="export">
</a>
```

And now nothing is working. The event handler attached with the `.submit()` is not getting invoked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to your anchor tag like 
id="custom_targeting_param_form"

and then replace submit function with click as given by ShankarSangoli in your previous post.

> > $("#custom_targeting_param_form").submit(function(e){

to

> > $("#custom_targeting_param_form").click(function(e){

Comment: Thanks for the solution.                                     Actually my code inserts a value in the database based on the form submission. Now, the event handler inside the submit gets called properly , but the backend insertion is not happening. I guess there is something else that is preventing the form to submit properly.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter , thanks much for your reply . It was really useful. Below is what I did :

```
$("#save_report").click(function()
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : actionOfForm,
                        type : $('#custom_targeting_param_form').attr("method"),
                        data : $('#custom_targeting_param_form').serialize(),
                        success : function(){
                            alert('Report Saved successfully');
                            $("#showOrExportCustomTargetingReport").val('showReport');  
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

Hope this will be useful for other users facing the same problems as I did.